# Нужна ли запятая после ЕСТЬ?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли ставить запятые перед "ради" и "куда" в этом предложении?

> Вам есть, ради чего вставать, есть, куда идти.

Answer (score 5):

Правильно:  ***Вам есть ради чего вставать, есть куда идти.***

Розенталь  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=146#pp146

7. Внутри выражений типа есть чем заняться, есть над чем поработать, было о чём подумать, найду куда обратиться, не нахожу что сказать, осталось на что жить, состоящих из глагола быть, или найти (найтись), или остаться и вопросительно-относительного местоимения либо наречия (кто, что, где, куда, когда и т. д.) и неопределенной формы другого глагола, **запятая не ставится:** Тебе есть в мире что забыть (Л.); Бранить есть кому, кормить — некому (Даль); Есть чему и нравиться (Пис);

Comment: Спасибо, понятно.